# MultipartBodyBuilder как добавить String параметр?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-boot, multipartfile

У меня есть апи которое на вход принимает MultipartFormData

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("node-info")
class NodeInfoController(val nodeInfoService: NodeInfoService) {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun saveNodeInfo(@RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile) =   nodeInfoService.saveNodeInfo(file)
....

}
```

в методе saveNodeInfo(file) происходит десериализация в нужный мне тип данных и последующая обработка

```
override fun saveNodeInfo(file: MultipartFile) {
        val configWrapper = file.bytes.deserialize<SignedNodeInfo>()
        val name = configWrapper.raw.deserialize().legalIdentities.first().name
    ...
}
```

Сейчас я обращаюсь к данному апи посредством Spring web client

```
 override fun registerNodeInfo(nodeInfoFile: File): Mono<NodeInfoContainer> {
        val multipartBodyBuilder = MultipartBodyBuilder().apply {
            part("file", object : ByteArrayResource(nodeInfoFile.readBytes()){
                override fun getFilename(): String {
                    return nodeInfoFile.name
                }
            })
        }
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/node-info")
                .syncBody(multipartBodyBuilder.build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono()
    }
```

где передается файл в качетсве параметра.

сейчас мне нужно в метод saveNodeInfo добавить еще один String параметр token

```
override fun saveNodeInfo(file: MultipartFile, token : String ){
...
}
```

Как я могу передать еще один параметр в апи saveNodeInfo посредством MultipartBodyBuilder ?

Проект на Spring-Boot, язык Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Я кое-то предложу, но не ругайтесь, если идея вам не понравиться) Итак, метод **saveNodeInfo()** определен в некотором классе **А()**. Возможно, это класс уже переопределен вами в класс **B() : A()**. Если нет, то его нужно переопределить. Тогда в классе **B** можно:

Определить глобальную переменную:

```
private var token: String = ""
```

Создать метод, получающий на вход 2 параметра и запускающий ваш метод, внутри которого вы можете использовать параметр token:

```
fun saveNodeInfo(file: MultipartFile, token : String ){
    this.token = token
    saveNodeInfo(file)
}
```

Вот такая вот идея.